# Error when trying to run windows steam

Tags: steam

Sorry if this has been posted somewhere before but I tried to install windows steam on linux as soon as steam opens it says there is an error encountered problem and forces it closed did I do something wrong?

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use a tutorial? Try the command suggested here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444&iTestingId=85093&bShowAll=true

Comment: I just installed it from the website ill try that see if it works thax @Zacharee1

Comment: I did that and I was able to get into steam i have a game downloading now hope it works out thx again

Comment: No problem. I'l put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this WineHQ page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444&iTestingId=85093&bShowAll=true), you need to run a command.

Open a terminal and run:

```
wine reg add 'HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam' /v DWriteEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
```

Steam should now run.